# Solve $y^{\prime\prime} = -(1+(y^\prime)^2)^{3/2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The question is as the topic, I am sorry I don't know how to type it as formal math signs.  Besides, I am always confused " are y' and dy/dx same? "

In this question, what is the meaning of y'?   it is equal to dy/dx (no x in this question at all), or dy means the change of y, like Δy?

Any help welcome. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This equation actually means that the curvature of $y(x)$ is equal to $1$. Meaning it's a circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y'$ is another symbol for ${d y \over d x}$

and

$y''$ is another symbol for ${d^2 y \over d x^2}$.

You didn't ask, but the solution to your equation is:

$y_1(x) = I \sqrt{-1 + x^2 - 2 x c_1 + c_1^2 + c_2}$

and

$y_2(x) = -I \sqrt{-1 + x^2 - 2 x c_1 + c_1^2 + c_2}$,

where the constants depend upon initial conditions.

Comment: Hi David, shall you please show me how to get that? And why we have two constants?

Comment: Zabbka:  We have two constants because this is a second-order equation (i.e., up to two derivatives on the variable $y$).  You will need to take a course in differential equations to see the solution method—too involved to explain here.